# Kafka topic with different format of data

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have written some avro data to the topic “test-avro” using Kafka-avro-console-producer.
Then I have written some plain text data to the same topic “test-avro” using Kafka-console-producer.
After this, all the data in the topic got corrupted. Can anyone explain what caused this to happen like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot use the `avro-console-consumer` (or a Consumer with an Avro deserializer) anymore to read those offsets because it'll assume all data in the topic is Avro and use Confluent's `KafkaAvroDeserializer`.

The plain `console-producer` will push non-Avro encoded UTF-8 strings and use the `StringSerializer`, which will not match [the wire format expected for the Avro deserializer](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format)

The only way to get past them is to know what offsets are bad, and wait for them to expire on the topic, or reset a consumer group to begin after those messages. Or, you can always use the `ByteArrayDeserializer`, and add a bunch of conditional logic for parsing your messages to ensure no data-loss.

**tl;dr** The producer and consumer must agree on the data format of the topic.